# Apply a style to a control in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a component that handles my edit boxes in react. One thing I do is passing in a prop called required:

```
<div className="col">
      <EditBox labelText="Firstname" data={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleFirstnameChange} required={true} />
</div>
```

(Is there a way just to send 'required' instead of 'required={true}'?)

My component then checks this value, and onKeyUp, validates the data the user has entered. (Not sure how to set the initial state...). I'd use onChange, but that's been assigned to my callback, as it updates the state.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Editbox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.validation = this.validation.bind(this);

        var style = {
            "border-color": "red"
        }

    }



    validation(e)
    {
        if(this.props.required===true && !!!e.target.value)
        {
            console.log("Box is invalid!");
            return;
        }

        console.log("Box is valid");

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="top-buffer">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <span>{this.props.labelText}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.props.data} onKeyUp={this.validation} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I then apply the style, or remove the style when I do the validation? I have a validation function, that I create the style, but I need to apply at. For now, I am just console logging.

Comment: You can create another class, assign that style to it in CSS, and later simply change the className based on the condition, should be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

your EditBox component can have a valid key on its state, that way you can track whether your input is valid or not

```
class EditBox extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valid : false
  }

  validate = (e) => {
    const { required } = this.props;
    const { value } = e.target; 
    if (required && value.length === 0) {
      this.setState({ valid : false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ valid : true })
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { label, required, name, data, onChange } = this.props;
    const { valid } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{border : `1px solid ${valid ? 'black' : 'red'}`}}>
        <label>
           {required && '*'}
           {label}
        </label>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name={name}
          value={data}
          onKeyUp={this.validate}
          onChange={onChange} 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and a [demo](https://jsbin.com/liqovabinu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)